# Getting response in success callback of async.js waterfall method

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have the following function using `async.js` `waterfall` method:

```
async.waterfall([
  funcOne,
  funcTwo,
  function upload(items, next) {
    async.each(items,
        function(item, callback) {
            s3.putObject({
                Bucket: srcBucket,
                Key: item.key,
                Body: item.data,
                ContentType: item.contentType,
                Metadata: {
                  type: 'thumbnail'
                }
            }, function(err,data){
              callback(err,data);
            });
        },
        function(err,response) {
          next(err,response);
        });
  }],
  function(err,response) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('------ SUCCESS',response);
    }
  }
);
```

I want to get access to the `async.each` response in the `success` callback for `waterfall`.

I've tried a few different flavors of doing `callback(err,data) => next(err,response)` and `------ SUCCESS` is always *undefined*.

What am I missing?

Comment: try with  async.map which will give you the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what I was missing was using `async.map()` instead of `async.each()`. `async.each()` does not return values, as one would expect. Using `async.map()` will give you a return response so you can pass values down the chain.